# Layout with a header at the top and a footer at the bottom in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create an Android screen layout that I think is pretty simple. I basically want a header at the top and a footer at the bottom, along with an EditText box that fills the rest of the screen space. The header and EditText box is working fine, but I cannot seem to get my footer to display. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
               android:src="@drawable/droidiary"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ImageView>
    <View android:id="@+id/view1" 
          android:layout_height="2dip"
          android:background="#FFAAAAFF" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </View>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                  android:hint="Type about your day..."
                  android:text="" 
                  android:id="@+id/txtEntry" 
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </EditText>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View android:id="@+id/view2" 
                  android:layout_height="2dip"
                  android:background="#FFAAAAFF" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            </View>
            <TextView android:text="TextView" 
                      android:id="@+id/textView1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Like I said, everything works except my footer. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is too complicated for what you want to achieve. I would recommend to avoid `RelativeLayout` unless you absolutely have to use it.

Here is a simple example of how to create header/content/footer layout using `LinearLayout`:
(note the `layout_weight` in the `content` element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView                   
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:text="Header" />

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="false" 
                android:hint="Type about your day..."
                android:text="" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView                   
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:text="Footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for simplifying my over-engineering

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a lot of extra unneeded layouts. This will layout the three areas for you and you can put anything inside them or just make them a view control. The height of each area will be 25%, 50%, 25%. If you don't want percentages, remove the weights from the header and footer and set their width value but leave the weight of the EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
   <View android:id="@+id/headerView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="2" />
   <EditText android:id="@+id/editBox"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1" />
   <View android:id="@+id/footerView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood which part of your layout is header and footer, add this line:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
```

to EditText